# Ffmpeg - multi overlay - where is the mistake?

Tags: ffmpeg, overlay

Four videos should be evenly spread over the entire area.
I am trying to use this code, and I cannot find an error.
Size of the logo.png file 1920x1080.

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i logo.png -i 01.mp4 -i 02.mp4 -i 03.mp4 -i 04.mp4 -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=960x540[a]; [2:v]scale=960x540[b]; [3:v]scale=960x540[c]; [4:v]scale=960x540[d]; [0:v][a]overlay=0:0:shortest=1[e]; [0:v][b]overlay=960:0:shortest=1[e]; [0:v][c]overlay=540:0:shortest=1[e]; [e][d]overlay=0:960[video]" -y -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:00:05 -b 3000k -map "[video]" 05.mp4
```

Audio track from video "01.mp4"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each new overlay has to use the previous overlay as main input.

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -i logo.png -i 01.mp4 -i 02.mp4 -i 03.mp4 -i 04.mp4
 -filter_complex
    "[1:v]scale=960x540[a]; [2:v]scale=960x540[b]; [3:v]scale=960x540[c]; [4:v]scale=960x540[d];
     [0:v][a]overlay=0:0:shortest=1[e]; [e][b]overlay=960:0[f];
     [f][c]overlay=540:0[g]; [g][d]overlay=0:960[video]"
 -y -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:00:05 -b 3000k -map "[video]" -map 1:a? -c:a copy 05.mp4
```

Comment: How to make the output video match the duration of video 01.mp4?

Comment: Add `-shortest`